# matching function in excel using lookup

Tags: vba, excel, lookup, vlookup

Hi guys I have an excel file, I have placed it here [for reference](http://filebin.ca/2hjDsTeOnuwX)

It has 2 worksheet, indicator and TTP,

Indicator has several columns but Indicator_TTP is the foreign Key here,

TTP has TTP_ID and other columns,

Now in indicator worksheet I wanted to get name from TTP worksheet so tried to use lookup function. [I followed this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/715620-can-we-combine-data-two-sheets-based-column-we-use-primary-key.html)

Unfortunately it is giving me wrong result.

I am using this formula `=LOOKUP(G:G,TTPs!A:A,TTPs!D:D)`

My concept is Look for all values of G in TTPs sheet in Columns and on match return TTPs D column, Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Did you sort the values in `TTPs!A:A` in ascending order?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes I did as you can see in attached file.

Comment: I make it habit not to download files from the internet sorry, got burned once.  So I was guessing.

Comment: Please upload your file to a free service, where I don't need to register or login to download anything.

Comment: @ScottCraner this is clean plus virtual machines rock :)

Comment: @teylyn http://filebin.ca/2hjDsTeOnuwX

Comment: Excel gives me a warning. This is an .xls file but Excel says file format and extension don't match. File could be corrupted or unsafe. I'm not opening that.

Comment: @teylyn thank you this is because the file is created dynamically via python scripts that download data from api, any ways virustotal.com says 0 virus in it.

Comment: If you open the downloaded file with 7zip, you can clearly see its a .xlsx file but mistakenly using .xls extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure why you don't just use `VLOOKUP()`.

It would work if you give VLOOKUP a proper table_array. You cannot give it 1 column to return the 4th column!

In your column K in **Indicators**, use formula below then double click the bottom right square dot to auto fill down.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2,TTPs!A:D,4,FALSE),"TTP not found")
```

[image: sample data]

Comment: thanks alot,  works like a charm, but why does it shows "0" and what does "TTPs!A:D" means ? we are matching G2 with A to D ???

Comment: @require_once The `TTPs!A:D` is the lookup range, It is using column A the full column to find G2, If found it returns the 4th column, that is what the `4` in the formula means, which in this case is column D.  The `0` happens because it finds a match in column A but there is no value or a `0` in Column D at that row.

Comment: @require_once Since your sheet **TTPs** is sheet is not ascending sorted on Col A (uploaded wrong file?), the `lookup()` returns nearest result if no exact match - which the exact match is what you need. Thanks Scott for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

The lookup function takes ([lookup value],[lookup vector],[result vector]) as arguments-try switching the first argument you enter (G:G) to a single cell(G1) and drag it down for a list of results in the column.

=lookup($G1,TTPs!A:A,TTPs!D:D) then drag down.

Comment: that still returns the same reuslt